# MediaPlayer release problem in ImageView slider

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have the below adapter class. Can someone tell me where and how do I release the sound so that the sound stops playing on new image?

My idea is to play `Obj1` sound on **Obj1 image**, `Obj2` sound on **Obj2 image**, and so on and release a sound when another one starts playing.
Currently the correct sound of the correct image is playing but when I swipe an image, the sound from previous view is still playing along with the current view sound.

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context My_context;
    LayoutInflater My_inflater;
    MediaPlayer MyObj1_mp3, MyObj2_mp3, MyObj3_mp3, MyObj4_mp3;
    public int[] My_images = { R.drawable.MyObj1,R.drawable.MyObj2,R.drawable.MyObj3,R.drawable.MyObj4 };
    public String[] My_title = { "MyObj1","MyObj2","MyObj3","MyObj4" };
    public MyPagerAdapter(Context My_context) { this.My_context = My_context; }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return My_title.length; }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) { return (view==(ConstraintLayout)object); }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int My_position) {
        My_inflater = (LayoutInflater) My_context.getSystemService(My_context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = My_inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_My_custlayout,container,false);
        ConstraintLayout My_constraint_layout = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_My);
        ImageView My_slide = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.MyView);
        TextView My_text= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.My_txt);
        My_slide.setImageResource(My_images[My_position]);
        My_text.setText(My_title[My_position]);

        MyObj1_mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(My_context,R.raw.MyObj1);
        MyObj2_mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(My_context,R.raw.MyObj2);
        MyObj3_mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(My_context,R.raw.MyObj3);
        MyObj4_mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(My_context,R.raw.MyObj4);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (My_position == 0){ MyObj1_mp3.start(); }
                else if (My_position == 1){ MyObj2_mp3.start(); }
                else if (My_position == 2){ MyObj3_mp3.start(); }
                else { MyObj4_mp3.start();}
            }
        });
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    { container.removeView((ConstraintLayout)object); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess using more than MediaPlayer instance is not that right as you want only one of them to play at a time; so you can use a single MediaPlayer instance.

So, you can remove MyObj1_mp3, MyObj2_mp3, MyObj3_mp3, & MyObj4_mp3, and just create `mediaPlayer`.

And each time you want to play a raw resource, just release the mediaPlayer resources and reiterate its creation with the new resource. You can just create a method that takes that resource as an argument.

So, remove below:

```
    MyObj1_mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(My_context,R.raw.MyObj1);
    MyObj2_mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(My_context,R.raw.MyObj2);
    MyObj3_mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(My_context,R.raw.MyObj3);
    MyObj4_mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(My_context,R.raw.MyObj4);
```

And add those:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int My_position) {

    // ..... rest of code

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            releaseMediaPlayer();
            if (My_position == 0){ setupMediaPlayer(R.raw.MyObj1); }
            else if (My_position == 1){ setupMediaPlayer(R.raw.MyObj2); }
            else if (My_position == 2){ setupMediaPlayer(R.raw.MyObj3); }
            else { setupMediaPlayer(R.raw.MyObj4); }
        }
    });
}

private void setupMediaPlayer(int resource) {
    // add track file
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(My_context, resource);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton. I've been banging my head around everywhere (consider me a typical novice) but you're my savior. Thanks again for the magic touch. Most probably, I'll come back again with some half cooked codes.

Comment: Hey @Zain, I have one observation now.  The sounds are releasing for all the items in the ViewPager ImageView but not for the first and last item.  For example, I click on image0 and it plays sound0 but as I swipe to image1 still the sound0 is playing. Similarly, when I click on last image, the last sound plays but when I swipe back to 2nd last image, still the last sound is playing.  I have already put releaseMediaPlayer() in  destroyitem() method.  For rest of the images, sounds are playing and releasing as expected. Could you suggest a way ahead here?

Comment: Hello @SumanChhetri that looks odd, let me have a look

Comment: @SumanChhetri I am afraid that this is due to `ViewPager adapter` caching issue, so it might be that it destroyed items, but not the `mediaPlayer` when it needs to move away off the edge items (item 1, 4) which they have the problem;. So when you try to click item 2 after item 1 is destroyed, then `mediaPlayer` object now is `null` before it's released, so calling `releaseMediaPlayer()` has no effect, and the audio is still playing in background as it's already consumed by the system audio service, as a first step, I suggest to call `releaseMediaPlayer()` inside `destroyItem()`

Comment: Thank you again for looking into it and providing those precious suggestions. I already have called `releaseMediaPlayer()` inside `destroyItem()` but that didn't help. So, I have one more question related to it. If the sound cannot be released on edge items, can there be a button on each ImageView which plays the related sound on click?

Comment: ImageView is just like any other view, that you can attach onClickListener to it, there is no underlying views in it. but I want you to do something for testing purpose .. just create a dummy project that has 4 ImageViews and add the MediaPlayer into the activity without a ViewPager .. I just need to confirm the problem in ViewPager itself.

Comment: After you gave some suggestions, I got an idea to `releaseMediaPlayer()` in `instantiateItem()` method, and guess what..!! the problem is resolved, yay... StackOverflow is such a wonderful platform for collaborating and making things work and I'm thankful that I got your kind help. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should move MediaPlayer operations to the place where you called the PagerAdapter.you should implement ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener to pager instance.In this way, you listen current item's index. when change current item's index, you can change sound.

Comment: Thanks @Serhat for your suggestion, however Zain has given a perfect solution for me.